# how to add date and time to a directory name in java

Tags: java, datetime

Hi I want to create a local directory with date and time in the name like below

directoryname_date_time

How can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: AFAIK, the only way you can do it is by writing code.

Comment: google is your friend. "how to create a directory java" and "get date and time as string java"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

Try something and if you can't figure it out, then come to SO and ask a question mentioning what you've tried. Take a look at this and see if it helps you figure out the solution to your question:

```
Date date = new Date(); //creates a date based on current date/time

//provides a formatting string for your eventual output
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); //prints something like "2013-01-04"
```

So now you've got the date as a string and you should be able to figure out how to attach it to the directory name.

You can create better format strings for your SimpleDateFormat by checking out the API at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: You should just send him your email address, it would reduce clutter here on SO :)

Comment: But then he'd spam me with emails to write his app :(.

Comment: Point being, he's spamming us now by not doing any work on his own and your answer enabled that behavior. Note too that he has neither up voted nor accepted your answer.